# How can I change the direction of an arrow in PlantUML Beta syntax?

Tags: uml, plantuml

With the **PlantUML Standard Syntax** it is possible to influence the **direction of an arrow**:

```
@startuml
(*) -up-> "We went up"
-right-> "We went right"
--> "We went down because this is standard"
-left-> (*)
@enduml
```

[image]

I want to do the same but in the PlantUML **Beta Syntax**.

What I have found is the possibility to influence the color and style of the arrow like in the example below:

```
@startuml
    start
    :We went down because this is standard;
    -[#green,dashed]-> We went down with a green and dashed arrow;
    :We went down again;
    stop
@enduml
```

[image]

But this doesn't work with directions when trying `-right->`, `-r->`, `-[right]->`or anything similar.

**Is there a possibility to influence the direction of an arrow in PlantUML Beta Syntax?**

Comment: At least there seems to be no possibility, neither with some general layout setting like `left to right direction`. Do you need  to use the Beta Syntax or can you keep the old one?

Comment: I think the beta syntax aligns with time going down (like in sequence diagrams). So, the directions are not part of the diagrams, because sequential actions should flow down. Now, in your question, you imply that you're trying to color arrows (and that's why you want the beta syntax). Is your question really about how to do colored arrows with the legacy syntax (so you can also control direction)?

Comment: Hi Fuhrmanator, Hi HaeschenAufGras, I would prefer an answer on how to change directions in the beta syntax. The reason is, that we are using beta syntax for our other diagrams as well and I'd like to stay consistent.  But since so far (since two and a half years) nobody has answered that, I assume that is not possible. So if you have an answer to **How can I color arrows  in the legacy syntax?** that would be welcome, too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently:

**It is not possible to change the direction of an arrow in PlantUML Beta syntax.**

I posted this question in January 20**20** and there is still no answer although quite some people have looked at the question. Also two people have commented on this likely not beeing possible (Thanks @HaeschenAufGras and @Fuhrmanator).

You can see the details of why this is likely not possible in the comments under the original question.

If you know a way how the direction of an arrow can be changed in PlantUML Beta syntax please do post an answer. I'll be happy to change the accepted answer to that one ;-)